# Android I saved a photo in removable storage using SAF, but Gallery don't recognize it and I cannot open it

Tags: android, storage

I finally figure out how to save a photo in an arbitrary location in removable storage in Android by using a storage access framework.

However, I encounter another problem.

I successfully saved a photo in a path like `/storage/6265-6530/DCIM/Camera` but I cannot see the photo in Gallery. Moreover, I try to open the photo through the file browser but I cannot open it.

I connect the phone to the PC and I can open the photo I saved in PC.

So how to fix it?

below is my code:

```
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(reactContext, mUri);
DocumentFile file = pickedDir.createFile("image", "myPhoto.jpg");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file.getUri());
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) { //read is successful
   out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,file.getUri()));
```

I have called `sendBroadcast` to scan the file but still, the gallery didn't show my photo.

Comment: `but I cannot see the photo in Gallery`  That is normal.

Comment: `try to open the photo through the file browser but I cannot open it.`. That i dont believe. It should be possible. Please elaborate.

Comment: Android version?

Comment: Reboot your device.